# JQuery click function removeClass addClass sequential

Tags: jquery, click, hide, sequential

I want to click on a button, a div appears, when clicking the same button it should disappear.

Actually only appearing works, how to hide it again?

Skript:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
  $('#ui-block-a').removeClass('visuallyhidden').addClass('ui-block-a'), function(){
  $('#ui-block-a').addClass('visuallyhidden').removeClass('ui-block-a');
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="visuallyhidden" id="ui-block-a">
     <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" id="nav"></ul> 
 </div>
```

Here is try to use a callback, but it is not working...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the classes are correctly set from the beginning, you can use  [`.toggleClass()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/):

```
$('#ui-block-a').toggleClass('visuallyhidden ui-block-a');
```

Otherwise, if you *explicitly* want to add/remove classes, you can use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/):

```
$('#button').toggle(function() {
    $('#ui-block-a').removeClass('visuallyhidden').addClass('ui-block-a');

}, function(){
    $('#ui-block-a').addClass('visuallyhidden').removeClass('ui-block-a');
});
```

---

**Why your code does not work:**

You are *not* setting up a callback. You are executing two statements via the *comma operator*. The first part (`$('#ui-block-a').addClass('...').removeClass('...')`) will be executed as expected. The second part (`function() {...}`) will be evaluated as *function expression* and the result, a function, will be returned as overall result of the statement. But you are not assigning the result to anything, so it is just silently ignored.

E.g. if you'd do

```
// form is like `var foo = x, y;`
var foo = $('#ui-block-a').removeClass('...').addClass('...'), function(){
    $('#ui-block-a').addClass('...').removeClass(...');
};
```

then `foo` would refer to the function

```
function() { 
    $('#ui-block-a').addClass('...').removeClass('...');
}
```

But that is not what you want anyway. So putting a function there is legal, but has not special meaning and thus no effect.

Comment: thanks, works perfectly, it could be so easy if you know how :) i'll accept later (still blocked)

Answer (score 0):

Use `toggleClass`, sometimes `toggleClass` can be a bit temperamental so use an if statement and and variable.

in sudo code:

```
variable = 0

if variable = 0
{
    Show Div
    variable = 1
}
else if variable = 1
{
    Hide Div
    variable = 0
}
```